# Emulate Shaking Gesture / Nudging Gesture on Adobe AIR for Mobile?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, android-emulator, adobe, simulate

I'm trying to simply display the updated value of accelerometerX on a text input but I don't know how to simulate a shaking or nudging on the emulator that came with Flash Builder. Below is the code that I'm using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        title="MainView" creationComplete="onCreationComplete(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.sensors.Accelerometer;

            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var tShake:Accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
                tShake.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, onAccelerometerUpdate);
            }

            protected function onAccelerometerUpdate(event:AccelerometerEvent):void {
                sampleDisplay.text = event.accelerationX.toString();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:TextArea id="sampleDisplay" x="14" y="11"/>
</s:View>
```

Here's a video of my sad attempt at making it work. Of course it doesn't.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3uOOLnXd5qA

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe Device Central](http://www.adobe.com/products/devicecentral.html) supports emulating Accelerometer input, but I think it only supports Flash 10.2 projects. I see you are using Flash Builder on a mac, so if you are using FB4.6/Air 3.1/Flash 11 then I don't think it'll work.

Perhaps more importantly than that, I think Device Central is only bundled with Flash CS4+ (and the applicable CS bundles that include Flash). [Here is](http://www.riagora.com/2010/04/air-and-the-accelerometer/) a little tutorial about somebody talking about using it, but that doesn't help you if you dont have it.

Aside from that, I don't know of anyway in Flash Builder 4.6 to simulate accelerometer events, other than deploying to an actual device and testing there.

Comment: I'm using Flash Builder 4.5. And the Flex SDK 4.5.1. What does that say about my chances at your given solution?

Comment: it may be possible then, if you have access to Device Central (via an installation of Flash CS5.5). try loading the swf from the bin-debug folder into Device Central and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry for sounding quite newbish but how do I actually load the swf file? Where do I go?

Comment: @ShedoSurashu see [this document](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/devicecentral/cs/using/devicecentral_cs5_help.pdf) and see if that helps.